# Java Client for Wcf service fedarated with Adfs

Tags: wcf, adfs2.0, java-client

I have a wcf service which is connected to an adfs as a relaying party. This adfs is acting as a identity provider. now in client side there is a Java client which want to call the wcf service but before that it have to authenticated in adfs with username and pass for token. I have successfully done it for .Net client but do not have any idea for java client..Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

For web services, ADFS uses WS-Trust.

The Metro stack e.g. implements this but for a standalone client you probably need something like axis2 which implements this via [Apache Rampart](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/rampart/).

Comment: thnx for the ans..but how can i use it? Do you have any example or link??